# Changing x-axis of a ChartObject in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

If I want to change my x-axis to the data inside the range `G5:G105` over `Chart 2` then I put this into my VBA subroutine:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Q1'!$G$5:$G$105"
```

How do I make it such that I can have some arbitrary range INSTEAD OF the fixed `$G$5:$G$105`. I've tried to use

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Q1'!Range("G5").Resize(I, 1)"
```

where `I` is some `Integer` variable defined in a preceding part of the subroutine.

However it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid your range `"='Q1'!Range("G5").Resize(I, 1)"` is an illegal mix of a strings and code. Try this range instead: `Range("Q1!G5").Resize(i, 1)`.

Full example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChartTest()

    Dim i As Integer

    i = 2

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("Q1!G5").Resize(i, 1)

End Sub
```