# Automate Excel Graph after it goes blank

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Currently I am updating weekly graphs. After I copy and paste the data the graph goes blank. So I have to go to Layout -> Axes Primary Horizontal, and then I have to select show default  Axis. The I have to right click and format the Axis and then I have to move fixed to auto. Although that leaves a space on each side so I have to go back select fixed the subtract one from the maximum and add one to the minimum to have the graph correct.

The X-Axis is using  dates in 15 min intervals for a week. Is there a way to use a macro to automate this process? Using active.workbook

Example

- 9/3/2012 0:15
- 9/3/2012 0:30
- 9/3/2012 0:45
- 9/3/2012 1:00
- 9/3/2012 1:15
- 9/3/2012 1:30
- 9/3/2012 1:45

---

The following is what I got from the macro recorder. [image]

```
Sub Graph()
'
' Graph Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Windows("2013W21.xls").Activate

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 41161
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 41170
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 41162
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 41169
    Selection.Delete
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: A great way to start would be to turn on the Macro Recorder and record the steps you described in your question.

Comment: `Is there a way to use a macro to automate this process?` Yup, there sure is. A great way to start to learn how is to use the macro recorder when you do it manually. Then you can tweak the code the recorder spits out. If you get stuck, post the code you've garnered and tell us where you are stuck in getting it to suit your needs. We can help much easier that way ... See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: @Michael `Macro recorder` is a good start for Charting in Excel 2003 and 2010 but 2007...[Why is that? 1:](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76496). [2:](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937620). [3:](http://www.excelcharts.com/blog/excel-2007-charts-useless/) etc.. :)

Comment: I am not sure I am using Excel 2010, the company I am with has been around for a while though so may have been built with 2007

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277904/changing-x-axis-of-a-chartobject-in-vba similar I think but I cant understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub Tester()

```
Dim rngDates As Range, sht As Worksheet
Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction

Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set sht = ActiveSheet
Set rngDates = sht.Range(sht.Range("B5"), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

'set x-axis (with a padding of 1 hour either side)
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = wsf.Min(rngDates) - (1 / 28)
    .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = wsf.Max(rngDates) + (1 / 28)
End With
```

End Sub

This code solves the problem.