# Excel Graph becomes blank when X Axis

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]Here's my probably I am working with 15 minute intervals so when ever I update the data my Excel Graph becomes blank. Then when I go into settings to put it on auto it has a gap then I have to manually add 1 to Manually adjust the Fixed Values, thus is there a setting I can do to stop the graph from becoming blank or is possible to make a macro which removes toggles the graph and removes the spaces. This is what the 15 min looks like 10/1/2012 0:30
. I tried to use a macro to set the maximum and minimum to ranges but Excel 2010 didnt seem to allow that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automate Excel Graph after it goes blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158697/automate-excel-graph-after-it-goes-blank)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in XL2010:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rngDates As Range, sht As Worksheet
    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction

    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set rngDates = sht.Range(sht.Range("B5"), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

    'set x-axis (with a padding of 1 hour either side)
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = wsf.Min(rngDates) - (1 / 24)
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = wsf.Max(rngDates) + (1 / 24)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Set rngDates = sht.Range(sht.Range("Q3:Q674"), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp))

Comment: One quick question though is there a way to get the Range to call from another sheet in the same Excel Workbook. The Graph is on a page "Graph" and the Data is on a page "Data" the specific range being called is "B6:B677".

Comment: =Data!B6 is how I had Q3 reflect the B6 value and then I hide those values on the "Graph" sheet

Comment: If your data is on a different sheet then you just need to adjust the rngDates assignment to point to that sheet instead of the ActiveSheet.

Comment: Ok so would it be ActiveWorkbook.Data